# Как добавить определенный limit к определенной таблице при выводе SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Делаю общий вывод пока из 2-х таблиц, и нужно как то добавить лимит к каждой таблице при выводе. К примеру users = LIMIT 1, podarok = LIMIT 4 и.т.д? Как правильно это делается?
Мой sql:

```
SELECT `users`.id AS users_id, `podarok`.you_id  AS podarok_id ,`users`.*
   FROM `users` , `podarok` WHERE `users`.id = '".intval($my_id)."' AND `podarok`.you_id = `users`.id
```

Comment: @Mike Скинул...

Comment: Эммм. в таком варианте не ясно. вы и так выбираете только одного пользователя и рядом в каждой записи инфа о подарках, зачем ему лимит, если он один. общий лимит 4 даст 4 записи с этим пользователем и 4 подарками

Comment: Непонятно, зачем здесь вообще таблица юзерс

Comment: @Mike Возможно я построил не правильно сам запрос. В общем задача такова, нужно вывести одного пользователя и все что связано с ним, подарки ( 4 ), подписки (6)... Из разных таблиц.

Comment: Если пользователь действительно только один, то делайте отдельными запросами. Иначе вы запутаетесь что к чему. Вы свой текущий запрос выполните, посмотрите что он выдаст. Инфа о пользователе будет 4 раза, и рядом по одному подарку. А если еще таблицу с 2 записями добавить в запрос, то получите 8 строк и подарки будут задвоены, а подписки по 4 раза одна и та же

Comment: @Mike Видел что можно выводить через union, не подскажите как построить запрос на моем примере? Чтобы можно было выводить к примеру в разные массивы, чтобы не былj путаницы? ( Но с одним запросов к базе ).

Comment: Нет смысла разнотипные данные выбирать одним запросом. несколько коротких запросов будут не медленне, чем один сложный, данные из которого надо будет потом на клиенте еще разделять на категории. Одним запросом в БД надо стараться делать когда данные действительно связаны между собой. Если бы вы попросили список вех пользователей с их подарками - тогда был бы смысл делать один запрос

Comment: @Mike Просто на странице профиля находятся данные, которые в разных таблицах и прикованы одним id. Из-за этого логичнее выводить одним запросом все эти данные, конечно если нужны какие то логические выполнения в ходе вывода, то это уж другая история.

Comment: ну скажем `select 'ПОДАРОК' as type, podarok_id from ... UNION select 'ПОДПИСКА', podp_id from подписки`. И потом вы будете делать один цикл чтения этого, который будет проверять `if(type=='ПОДАРОК') {то выводим в блок подарков} else if(type='ПОДПИСКА') {то в подписки}` учитывая что страница формируется не в перемешку, а сначала один блок, потом какое нибудь оформление и потом другой блок то такой цикл чтения будет дико запутанным

Comment: @Mike Хм, ну что же, значит проще и без сильной нагрузки можно сделать и через несколько запросов? К примеру на странице 5 выводов, это норма для сайта?

Comment: сильная нагрузка получается например если бы мы в цикле читали таблицу пользователей и для каждого из них выполняли отдельный запрос на получение подарков. А 5 отдельных запросов к разным таблицам, да еще по простому условию user_id=N (думаю по этому полю есть индекс в БД) - это быстро и это норма. Запрос с union проделает в БД абсолютно ту же работу. Накладные расходы только на компиляцию запросов. но у большого запроса компиляция медленне, оптимизатору надо рассмотреть больше вариантов. так что разница в скорости если и есть то она мизерна

Answer (score 1):

Для получения статистики из разных таблиц на определенного пользователя, можно использовать запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT count(id) FROM podarok WHERE user_id=u.id) as podarok_cnt, (SELECT count(id) FROM podpiska WHERE user_id=u.id) as podpiska_cnt FROM user u WHERE u.id=8
```

Comment: Можно глупый вопрос. Как выводить в php такой запрос? Я просто не понял как выводить такие вот запросы внутри запросов(

Comment: Если вы работаете через php-pdo, то хороший мануал - http://phpfaq.ru/pdo ; В php вы указываете запрос как есть, неважно сколько в нем под-запросов. В моем примере, результат каждого под- запроса складывается в свою колонку.

Comment: Ну я понимаю, просто можете скинуть вывод php как бы вы вывели сейчас из этого запроса...